# Fixing logical error when testing with describe in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to test the following and I get an error:

[image]

dateUtil.spec.ts:

```
import { isDay } from "./dateUtil";

describe("utils/dateUtil", () => {
  describe("isDate", () => {
    it("should determine if time of day is day or night", () => {
      const day = "Tue Dec 18 2018 12:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";
      const night = "Tue Dec 18 2018 20:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";

      expect(isDay(new Date(day))).toBeTruthy();
      expect(isDay(new Date(night))).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });
});
```

dateUtil.ts

```
export const isDay = (date: Date) => {
    const currentHour = date.getHours();
    return currentHour > 6 && currentHour < 18;
};
```

What am I missing and what do I need to do?

Comment: The timezone creates a time shift depending on the machine's timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Change time according to time zone. For example:

```
const night = "Sun Oct 04 2020 10:23:31 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)";
```